# ASP.Net MVC ViewModel for models with navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi I Have the following models:

```
public class Category()
{
 public int id{get;set;}
 public string Name{get;set;}
 public ICollection<Book> Books{get;set;}
}

public class Book()
{
  public int id{get;set;}
  public string Name{get;set;}
  public Book Book {get;set}
}
```

If I want to create a view to display Category, I would create a CategoryViewModel and create a strongly typed view for it.

if I also want to show the list of books for the categories, should I create a viewmodel for the books and use it as a collection in the categoryviewmodel. should I create viewmodel for all child types if I dont want to expose the ef models.

I've just started MVC, and i read couple of problems of directly exposing our entities to views. such as [this one](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) . so much appreciate any guidance on this. most of the posts online about view models only show 1 level. or they directly expose the entity.

Comment: if you need to show only a subset of properties of desired entity then create a DTO. if your DB model is the same as you want to show, then (depends on architecture) you can use original model.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, always use ViewModel-s to display data and InputModel-s to accept data from the user. In your case you should make a `BookViewModel` class that has 2 properties:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Then make an `IEnumerable<BookViewModel>` property in your `CategoryViewModel` class and pass it to your view.